# How to collapse multiple columns of data into two columns, with one indicator column and one data column

Tags: r

I ran an experiment with 3 conditions. The data is currently organized like this:

```
| X | Y | Z |
|   | 1 |   |
|   | 0 |   |
| 0 |   |   |
| 0 |   |   |
|   |   | 1 |
|   |   | 1 |
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
| Y | 1 |
| Y | 0 |
| X | 0 |
| X | 0 |
| Z | 1 |
| Z | 1 |
```

This is because it seems like a lot of analysis requires it in this format.

I am hoping there may be a function which does this transformation, as it seems like it might be rather common.

Edit:

I tried using the reshape suggestion below, but am having issues. It does not seem to be effecting the structure. My data must somehow be different from the constructed test data, but I am not sure how.

I am having some trouble with this and thought maybe you could help.

```
> simpleGame
   Q6.4 Q7.4 Q8.4
3               2
5               2
8          1     
11              2
13         1     
14    2          
16              1
17         1     
19    2          
23    2          
24              1
26    2          
28    2
```

But When I run melt, it does not seem to change anything:

```
> na.omit(melt(simpleGame))
Using Q6.4, Q7.4, Q8.4 as id variables
   Q6.4 Q7.4 Q8.4
1               2
2               2
3          1     
4               2
5          1     
6     2          
7               1
8          1     
9     2          
10    2          
11              1
12    2          
13    2
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Edit2: As requested, here is the dput of the data frame:

```
> dput(simpleGame)
structure(list(Q6.4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "1", "2", "Which do you choose?"
), class = "factor"), Q7.4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "1", "2", "Which do you choose?"
), class = "factor"), Q8.4 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "1", "2", "Which do you choose?"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Q6.4", "Q7.4", "Q8.4"), row.names = c(3L, 
5L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 28L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am thinking maybe it has something to do with the fact that these are actually factors? I don't know how to coerce an entire data.frame in to numeric, but I am thinking maybe that will do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `reshape2` and @Arun data structure:

```
na.omit(melt(df))
Using  as id variables
   variable value
3         X     0
4         X     0
7         Y     1
8         Y     0
17        Z     1
18        Z     1
```

**EDIT** using OP structure

```
dat.m <- melt(dat,measure.vars = c('Q6.4','Q7.4','Q8.4'))
dat.m[!(dat.m$value == ''),]
```

**Explanation**: All your columns are factors. The default behavior of `melt` is to take factors columns as id. As a workaround I tell melt that they are measurable variable so `melt` take the rownames as an id.  For the second part I just replace `na.omit` by `!(dat.m$value == '')` because I don't have NA within value, I have just empty character.

Comment: (+1) because you used the data I created :P

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble getting this working. I made an edit showing what I did. I would very much appreciate it if you took a look.

Thank you!

Comment: @evt can you type `dput(simpleGame)` and add he result to the OP?

Comment: Done.

I am thinking maybe it has something to do with the fact that these are actually factors? I don't know how to coerce an entire data.frame in to numeric, but I am thinking maybe that will do it.

Comment: Thanks. That works great. Do you mind explaining to me what was hanging it up?

Comment: @evt I add an explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to convert all of the factors a in data.frame to numeric? Kind of like as.numeric.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26184/discussion-between-agstudy-and-evt)

Answer (score 5):

If your data is like:

```
df <- structure(list(X = c(NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA), Y = c(1, 0, NA, NA, 
      NA, NA), Z = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1)), .Names = c("X", "Y", "Z"
      ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Try this:

```
na.omit(stack(df))
#    values ind
# 3       0   X
# 4       0   X
# 7       1   Y
# 8       0   Y
# 17      1   Z
# 18      1   Z
```

If you want your order:

```
na.omit(stack(df[c(2,1,3)]))[c(2,1)]
#    ind values
# 1    Y      1
# 2    Y      0
# 9    X      0
# 10   X      0
# 17   Z      1
# 18   Z      1
```